# Fragment popBackStack does not show previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to go to the previous fragment when the back button is pressed:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

This is how i inflate a fragment:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFragment,new Fileexplorer()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

However, using replace() will not do anything.
When i use add() it does work but everything gets overlapped.

Can someone help me out please thanks.

Comment: Fragments are already popped off the back stack - that's the default behavior of `onBackPressed()`. Why are you overriding that method at all?

Comment: It didn't work without `onBackPressed`

Comment: Then what does the default `onBackPressed()` do for you?

Comment: It shows the last fragment in the stack, but only when i use `add()`

Comment: So what does it do when you use the code actually in your question (i.e., `replace`)?

Comment: Absolutely nothing

Comment: As indicated, manually popping fragments is redundant. If you're adding to the back stack, add() or replace() should work. You have  bug somewhere. Show the full code.

Comment: The problem seems to be the Recycler View not saving its state for some reason.